# How do I make clones of a Sprite in Pygame?

Tags: python, class, pygame, sprite, clone

I am adding grass into a Scrolling Platform in Pygame & Python 2.7. The problem is, so far I've only got one strand of grass and I want there to be more. Basically I want there to be clones.

I've heard that Classes can make clones of Sprites, but I"m not exactly sure how classes work and how to even make one. All the tutorials I've found online have only made me more confused.

This part calls the `grass_rotate` function and also makes the `grass_rect`:

```py
grass_rect = grass.get_rect(topleft = (grass_x, 480 - player_y + 460))
grass_rotate(screen, grass_rect, (grass_x, 480 - player_y + 460), grass_angle)
```

This is the `grass_rotate` function:

```py
def grass_rotate(screen, grass_rect, topleft, grass_angle):
    rotated_grass = pygame.transform.rotate(grass, grass_angle)
    rotated_grass_rect = rotated_grass.get_rect(center = grass_rect.center)
    screen.blit(rotated_grass, rotated_grass_rect)
```

Comment: If you're trying to make a game without even knowing how classes work, it might be a sign that you're starting too big too early. You really should have a basic understanding of programming concepts before writing a big program.

Comment: yeah, maybe you're right

Comment: BTW, If you're just starting with Python you really shouldn't use the outdated and officially dead Python 2. Switch to Python 3.

Comment: I can't get Pygame into python 3 in PyCharm. It just keeps saying that the installation was unsuccessful.

Comment: I somewhat agree with @RandomDavis, although I don't want to discourage you.  Why not start with something *simple* like Pac Man - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pac-Man Get a sprite moving around a screen first, then add the pellets to eat (collisions), then add the score (text and fonts), then add the maze (collisions), then make the Pacman mouth-chomp (animation), then add sounds, then add the ghosts (AI), then make it scroll mazes (scrolling).  My point is: try to create a game in small achievable steps.  We're all here eager to help.

Comment: yeah well, AI is probably just gonna have me coming back to this website.

Comment: It doesn't have to be complex: http://gameinternals.com/understanding-pac-man-ghost-behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, to make rotated "clones" of a sprite, I think it would be best to make a sprite object based on `pygame.sprite.Sprite`, with options for bitmap rotation.

First lets make a really simple sprite:

```
class Grass( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    """ Creates a tuft of grass at (x,y) """
    def __init__( self, image, x, y ):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image    = image
        self.rect     = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = ( x, y )
```

<s>Because this is based on the [sprite library](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html), it automatically gets (inherits) the function `Grass.draw()` from `pygame.sprite.Sprite`.</s>

EDIT: The above paragraph is false.  Sprites do not inherit `draw()`, this is *only* part of Sprite Groups.  it is necessary to implement your own `draw()`, iff not using Sprite Groups:

```
    def draw( self, surface ):
        surface.blit( self.image, self.rect )
```

So to put it on the screen, we can just do:

```
grass_image = pygame.image.load( 'grass_clump.png' ).convert_alpha()
my_grass1 = Grass( grass_image, 10, 10 )
my_grass2 = Grass( grass_image, 50, 40 )

...

my_grass1.draw( window )
my_grass2.draw( window )

...
```

But we want to randomise the angle a bit, so each clump of grass is not so flat & regular.  One way to do this is to create a rotated copy of the image when the `Grass` sprite is initialised (`Grass.__init__()`).  PyGame already has a `rotozoom` [function](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.rotozoom) that does this.

So we basically have the same thing, except now we add an extra optional parameter for rotation.  I've defaulted it to `None`, and without the parameter, the class is free to choose its own random angle.

```
### Creates a sprite that is rotated slightly to the left or right
class Grass( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    """ Creates a tuft of grass at a jaunty angle """
    def __init__( self, image, x, y, rotation=None ):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        if ( rotation == None ):                                       # choose random angle if none
            angle = random.randrange( -15, 16 )                        # choose random angle if none
        self.image    = pygame.transform.rotozoom( image, angle, 1 )   # rotate the image
        self.rect     = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = ( x, y )
```

Now we need to put all this together.  One of the very useful features of PyGame and Pygame's Sprite library is Sprite Groups.  I don't want to go into huge detail here, but essentially it allows you act on a whole bunch of sprites at the same time, making the code much easier.

So now we want lots of clones of grass, so we just make 50 of them, and add to a new group:

```
### create lots of grass sprites, adding them to a group
grass_image = pygame.image.load( 'grass_clump_48.png' ).convert_alpha()
all_grass_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
for i in range( 50 ):
    new_x     = random.randrange( WINDOW_WIDTH )
    new_y     = random.randrange( WINDOW_HEIGHT )
    new_grass = Grass( grass_image, new_x, new_y )
    all_grass_sprites.add( new_grass )
```

To draw these to the window, you could loop through all sprites in the group with a `for()` statement.  But that's not necessary, because the sprite group can do this for us already:

```
all_grass_sprites.draw( window )   # draws all the grass sprites
```

[image: grass_sprites_clones]

Too easy right?!

The clump of grass is from [Open Clip Art](https://openclipart.org/download/167345/grasswip1.svg) (Public Domain Licensed.)

Here's the reference code:

```
import pygame
import random

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH    = 400
WINDOW_HEIGHT   = 400
WINDOW_SURFACE  = pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF

GREEN = ( 130, 220,   0 )  # background colour

### Creates a sprite that is rotated slightly to the left or right
class Grass( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    """ Creates a tuft of grass at a jaunty angle """
    def __init__( self, image, x, y, rotation=None ):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        if ( rotation == None ):                                       # choose random angle if none
            angle = random.randrange( -15, 14 )                        # choose random angle if none
        self.image    = pygame.transform.rotozoom( image, angle, 1 )   # rotate the image
        self.rect     = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = ( x, y )


### Initialisation
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), WINDOW_SURFACE )
pygame.display.set_caption("Grass Sprite Clones")

### create lots of grass sprites, adding them to a group
grass_image = pygame.image.load( 'grass_clump_48.png' ).convert_alpha()
all_grass_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
for i in range( 50 ):
    new_x     = random.randrange( WINDOW_WIDTH )
    new_y     = random.randrange( WINDOW_HEIGHT )
    new_grass = Grass( grass_image, new_x, new_y )
    all_grass_sprites.add( new_grass )

### Main Loop
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False
while not done:

    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True
        elif ( event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP ):
            # On mouse-click
            pass

    # Update the window, but not more than 60fps
    window.fill( GREEN )
    all_grass_sprites.draw( window )   # draws all the grass sprites
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Clamp FPS
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```